# С помощью регулярных выражений выбрать в строке все кроме скобок и строки в скобках

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка - "Одесса, Киевское шоссе (ран. Ленинградское шоссе), 27"
Как получить все кроме скобок и строки в скобках?
Как подобрать регулярное выражение для этой задачи?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const re = /([^(]*)(?:\([^)]*\))/g;

console.log(
  'Одесса, Киевское шоссе (ран. Ленинградское шоссе), 27'
    .replace(re, (_, g1) => g1.trimEnd())
);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!))